# How to create correlation of data using Scatter chart on Power BI

Tags: powerbi, relationship, scatter-plot, cardinality

I am trying to link two sets of data from a survey of 40 respondents together to form a correlation. One of it is the age range, whereas the other is the monthly spending range (does not matter which info is on which axis). I figured that using a scatter chart may be an interesting way to bring out the data insights, but I am unable to do so as I am not so familiar with Power BI yet.

I clicked around the various possible options and changed the values (e.g. from "Below $500" to "450"). I also tried to create a relationship between the two (1:1) in 'Model view' but the error message I got was "The cardinality you selected isn't valid for this relationship".